# *-isomorphism and spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

‎‎‎$A$ is a ‎‎‎‎$‎‎C^∗$-algebra and $P(A)$ is a set of projection of it. Assume that $A$ ‎admits a‎ ‎strictly ‎positive ‎element ‎‎‎‎‎$a$ ‎such ‎that ‎‎‎‎‎$‎‎‎‎σ(a)‎-\{‎0\}$ ‎is ‎discrete‎.

I want to prove that $‎‎A$ admits ‎an ‎approximate ‎unit ‎‎$‎‎(p_n:\forall n \in N, p_n \in P(A))$

If I can prove that $‎‎C^∗(a)$ ‎is ‎*-isomorphic ‎to $‎‎‎‎C_0(‎‎‎σ(a)-‎\{‎0\})$ ‎‎, my problem is solved.

Because I know that
‎$‎‎C_0(X)$ ‎admits ‎an ‎approximate ‎unit ‎‎$‎‎(p_n:\forall n \in N, p_n \in P(A))$ ‎if ‎and ‎only ‎if ‎‎
‎$‎‎X=‎\cup X_n‎$ ‎such ‎‎that $‎‎\forall n,X_n $ is ‎compact ‎and ‎open ‎sets.

‎
Q:Why can we say that $‎‎C^∗(a)$ is ‎ ‎*-isomorphic ‎to $‎‎‎‎C_0(‎‎‎σ(a)-‎\{‎0\})$?Is it true?Define *-isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is solved by the following important fact which has been proved by Arens & Kadison 1n 1968 (see their paper: Pure state and approximate identities)

Theorem (Arense & Kadison). Let $a$ be an strictly positive in a C*-algebra $A$. The $\{a^{\frac{1}{n}}\}$ forms an approximate identity for $A$.

In your problem, you assumed  $\sigma(a)$ is discrete. Therefore it is countable, namely $\{t_n\}_0^{\infty}$ where $t_0=0$. Now take $p_n=\sum_1^n \chi_{_{\{t_k\}}}(a)$ (since the spectrum is countable then $\chi_{_{\{t_k\}}}(a)$'s are all in $A$). The sequence of projections forms an approximate of identity.

Comment: $σ(a)-{0}$ is  discrete.why do you claim it is countable?

Comment: Uncountable subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ are all  non-discrete.

Comment: I read this paper.that is excellent.

Comment: also I know if $a$ is strictly positive then $u_n=a(a+1/n)^{-1}$ is an approximate unit for $A$